# Python GSpead On-Change Listener?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I'm making a script that checks a google sheet from a google form and returns the result as a live-feed visualization of a poll. I need to figure out how to update the value counts, but only when the google sheet is updated, as opposed to checking every 60 seconds (or something).

Here is my current setup:

```
string = ""

while True:
    responses = gc.open("QOTD Responses").sheet1
    data = pd.DataFrame(responses.get_all_records())
    vals = data['Response'].value_counts()
    str = "{} currently has {} votes. \n{} currently has {} votes.".format(vals.index[0], vals[0], vals.index[1],
                                                                           vals[1])
    if(str != string):
        string = str
        print(string)
    time.sleep(60) # Updates 1440 times per day
```

I'm almost certain that there has to be a better way to do this, but what would that be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with Python alone. You'll need to integrate with a [trigger function from Google Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

You could use the onEdit trigger function to send a signal to your python script (via an http call for example).

> To use a simple trigger, simply create a function that uses one of
> these reserved function names:
>
> - onOpen(e) runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document,
>   presentation, or form that the user has permission to edit.
> - onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.